# Chess PGN: Error in paste... result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes

Tags: r, chess

I'm using the library `bigchess` in R to read in a 3GB PGN file, see source here: https://github.com/rosawojciech/bigchess

Reading it in like so:

```
df <- read.pgn(paste0(path, file), add.tags = c("UTCDate", "UTCTime", "WhiteElo",  "BlackElo", "WhiteRatingDiff", "BlackRatingDiff", "WhiteTitle", "BlackTitle","TimeControl", "Termination"), n.moves = T, extract.moves = -1, stat.moves = T, big.mode = F, quiet = F, ignore.other.games = F)
```

I get the following error -

> "Error in paste(subset(r2, tmp1 == "Movetext", select = c(tmp2))[, 1],
>   :    result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes"

Based on internet searches this exists because R cannot store a character vector in memory that is greater than 2Gb.  Is there a way to override this limit, or otherwise deal with the issue?

Comment: FWIW https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pigeon/blob/master/R/pgn-to-sql.R (github/gitlab hrbrmstr/pigeon) has a way to get these files into a sqlite db which would enable out-of-memory operations on the columns/records.

Comment: I forgot about this fantastic library! I'm using bigchess right now because it allows for the import of custom tags (e.g. BlackElo and WhiteElo).  Can pigeon do this?  It'd be ideal to also extract clk and eval tags within move notation, and be able to skip import of games where Black or White Elo doesn't exceed some value (e.g. 2200).